# How can I tell dart that it should use the latest version of the packages when using "dart pub global activate"?

Tags: dart, pub.dev

I'm trying to install the package [spec_cli](https://pub.dev/packages/spec_cli). For this, I'm using the `dart pub global activate spec_cli` command.

However, there is an issue in the package `spec_cli` in version `0.1.2+2` or lower. To fix this, the author released `0.1.3`. Unfortunately, `dart pub global actiavte spec_cli` still uses `0.1.2+2`:

```bash
dart pub global activate spec_cli
+ _fe_analyzer_shared 49.0.0.3s)
+ analyzer 5.1.0
+ ansi_styles 0.3.2+1
+ args 2.3.1
+ async 2.9.0
+ boolean_selector 2.1.0
+ charcode 1.3.1
+ cli_util 0.3.5
+ collection 1.16.0
+ conventional_commit 0.4.3+1 (0.5.0 available)
+ convert 3.0.2
+ coverage 1.6.1
+ crypto 3.0.2
+ dart_test_adapter 0.2.0
+ duration 3.0.12
+ file 6.1.4
+ freezed_annotation 1.1.0 (2.1.0 available)
+ frontend_server_client 3.0.0
+ glob 2.1.0
+ graphs 2.1.0
+ http 0.13.5
+ http_multi_server 3.2.1
+ http_parser 4.0.1
+ io 1.0.3
+ js 0.6.4
+ json_annotation 4.7.0
+ logging 1.0.2
+ matcher 0.12.12
+ melos 1.5.2 (2.7.1 available)
+ meta 1.8.0
+ mime 1.0.2
+ mustache_template 2.0.0
+ node_preamble 2.0.1
+ package_config 2.1.0
+ path 1.8.2
+ platform 3.1.0
+ pool 1.5.1
+ pub_semver 2.1.1
+ pubspec 2.3.0
+ quiver 3.1.0
+ riverpod 2.0.2
+ shelf 1.4.0
+ shelf_packages_handler 3.0.1
+ shelf_static 1.1.1
+ shelf_web_socket 1.0.2
+ source_map_stack_trace 2.1.0
+ source_maps 0.10.10
+ source_span 1.9.1
+ spec_cli 0.1.2+2 (0.1.3 available)
+ stack_trace 1.10.0
+ state_notifier 0.7.2+1
+ stream_channel 2.1.1
+ string_scanner 1.1.1
+ term_glyph 1.2.1
+ test 1.21.6
+ test_api 0.4.14
+ test_core 0.4.18
+ typed_data 1.3.1
+ uri 1.0.0
+ vm_service 9.4.0
+ watcher 1.0.1
+ web_socket_channel 2.2.0
+ webkit_inspection_protocol 1.2.0
+ yaml 3.1.1
```

You can see that the dart tool knows that there is a new version of `spec_cli` ("spec_cli 0.1.2+2 (0.1.3 available)").

But how can I use this update?

Comment: Makes sense, @RandalSchwartz. I'm going to file an issue at GitHub 

Comment: It has been fixed :) Indeed, it was an issue with the dependency of spec_cli. If you want, you can write an answer and I'm going to accept it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[moved from a comment]

It looks like `spec_cli` depends on some other packages that also need updating to talk to `freezed_annotation 2` instead of 1. You should file an issue with `spec_cli` with your output from trying to activate it.